# is there a relation between symmetric distribution and higher odd moments

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable and suppose that its probability function $f(x)$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.

Assume further that

・$E[X^{2n+1}]=0 \forall$ nonnegative integers $n$.

・$F(0)=1/2$, where $F(x)$ is the cumulative probability function of $X$.

Then $f(x)$ is an even function over $\mathbb{R}$？

Thank you!

Comment: No bound on the growth of even moments?

Comment: That's right. But if necessary, we may assume that E(X^2n) is bounded. I would like to know the necessary and sufficient conditions for a probability density function to be an even function

Comment: If you don't bound the growth of even moments, then e.g. lognormal isn't determined by moments so you take a lognormal in the positive and something else in the negative direction.  If you bound the growth of moments so that the MGF is defined in a neighbourhood of $0$ then just invert the Laplace transform.